# Обращение к tableView в дочерней форме

Tags: c++, qt

Не удается обратиться к `tableView` созданной формы, ошибка:

> no member named 'tableView' in 'FoodMainForm'.

В главном окне `MainWindow` есть кнопка:

Файл mainwindow.cpp:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    food_form = new FoodMainForm();
    food_form->show();
    
    food_form->tableView->setModel(model);
}
```

Форма FoodMainForm:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вопросе не указано что за модель в tableView. Будем считать что QSqlTableView

Взаимодействите на минималках. В ui MainWindow закинут textEdit, куда будем логгировать выбор ячейки tableView в диалоге:

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QSqlError>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
private slots:
    // В этот слот будем принимать инфу что пользователь выбрал ячейку таблицы
    void dialogIndexSelected(int row,int col, QString val);
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "mydialog.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName("database.db3");
    if(!db.open())
        qDebug()<<db.lastError();
    // Создали объект формы диалога
    myDialog* dlg = new myDialog();
    // Когда диалог будет пулять сигнал выбора ячейки, обработаем в нашем слоте
    connect(dlg,SIGNAL(indexSelected(int,int,QString)),this,SLOT(dialogIndexSelected(int,int,QString)));
    // покажем окно диалога
    dlg->show();

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::dialogIndexSelected(int row, int col, QString val)
{
    // добавим в textEdit запись о том что выбрал пользователь
    ui->textEdit->append(QString("user was select item at row=%1, col=%2 with text='%3'").arg(row).arg(col).arg(val));
}
```

mydialog.h

```
#ifndef MYDIALOG_H
#define MYDIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QSqlResult>
#include <QSqlTableModel>

namespace Ui {
class myDialog;
}

class myDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit myDialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~myDialog();

private slots:
    // слот для сигнала, когда пользователь кликнул по ячейке 
    void on_tableView_clicked(const QModelIndex &index);

signals:
    // Такой сигналформа будет пулять когда пользователь выбрал ячейку
    void indexSelected(int row,int col, QString val);
private:
    Ui::myDialog *ui;
};

#endif // MYDIALOG_H
```

mydialog.cpp

```
#include "mydialog.h"
#include "ui_mydialog.h"

myDialog::myDialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::myDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    // Как я и говорил вся логика должна остаться в диалоге. Создадим модель, и настроим все остальное если надо
    QSqlTableModel* model = new QSqlTableModel();
    ui->tableView->setModel(model);
    model->setTable("TEST");
    model->select();
}

myDialog::~myDialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

// когда пользователь кликнул на ячейке
void myDialog::on_tableView_clicked(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    // эмитим сигнал в который передаем строку,столбец и текст выбранной ячейки
    emit indexSelected(index.row(),index.column(),index.data().toString());
}
```

Comment: Много написал. Спасибо! У меня второе окно правда QWidget

Comment: Еще не подскажешь как сделать, чтобы эти окна по-центру экрана открывались, не могу найти?

Comment: this.move(QApplication::desktop()->screen()->rect().center() - widget.rect().center()); или около того

Comment: Спасибо, большое!

Answer (score 1):

у вас два варианта: неправильно-некрасиво и правильно:

1. Сделать ui в FoodMainForm публичным (работать будет, но это нежелательно)
2. Все взаимодействие производить через сигналы-слоты. При этом вся логика дочернего окна должна быть именно в его классе

Comment: Нужно правильно и красиво. Как реализовать второй вариант?

Comment: Начните с того, что все касающееся внутреннего содержимого диалога реализуйте в его классе (это к примеру точно должно быть там food_form->tableView->setModel(model);) после того как диалог будет сам по себе функционален, можно будет определиться какие данные необходимо будет передавать между ним и классом главного окна и связать их соответствующими сигналами-слотами

Comment: перенес food_form в foodmainform.cpp, но тут он не видит эту переменную. Как победить?

Comment: Видимо вы немного не поняли о чем речь. Сделаю простенький пример с дочерней формой, размещу отдельным ответом